# What are `Zone.Identifier` files, and how do I prevent them from being created?

Tags: windows, file-io, filesystems, smb, network-drive

I often see files named 'blabla.exe:Zone.Identifier' when monitoring I/O with Process Monitor.
The files are seen on network-drives.

[image]

- What are `Zone.Identifier` files?
- What does the colon mean in the filename?
- Is the colon related the file's extended attributes?
- How do I prevent these files from being created when I copy code files from Windows Explorer to a WSL directory?

Comment: The only way that I found to deal with these annoying "ZoneIdentifier" files was by creating an alias `alias rzi="rm -rf **/*Zone.Identifier"` and running it right before copy files. The other good one was adding `**/*Zone.Identifier` on the `.gitignore` file of my projects.

Comment: To remove them (ubuntu): `find . -name "*Zone.Identifier" -type f -delete`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The text after the colon is an identifier for an "Alternate Data Stream". ADS is used to store meta-information about the file. For example, the Zone identifier stores whether the file was downloaded from the internet.

Some specific info [about URL Security Zones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537183.aspx), [Zone.Identifier Stream Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn392609.aspx)

See also [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976808.aspx), [Heysoft](http://www.heysoft.de/en/information/ntfs-ads.php?lang=EN) and this [article about alternative data streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809725/ntfs-alternate-data-streams).

Finally, here's [Streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/streams.aspx), the Sysinternals tool for ADS.

Comment: To remove problem on Windows side you need to configure it properly. Run gpedit.msc (Win + R) and go to User configuration > Administrative templates >Windows Components > Attachment Manager and set Do not preserve zone information in file attachments.

(to run gpedit.msc you’ll need Windows Professional)
--
found here: 
https://blog.realhe.ro/how-to-get-rid-of-zone-identifier-files/

Comment: Apart from not saving the file, is something else happening ?

Comment: @mtness That's worth posting a separate answer. If you do post one (like if there's an open question on Server Fault or something), I'll upvote. Here's a direct link to the [policy documentation](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/Default.aspx?PolicyID=26).

Comment: @mbomb007 I would, if I could, but this question here is closed as off-topic^^
I'll eventually have a look at the other sites, though.