# Using the R.NET assembly in IronPython

Tags: .net, r, ironpython

I would like to use the R statistical package for some data crunching in an [IronPython 2.7](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) application. I have found the [R.NET assembly](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/), which should make this possible. The problem is that IronPython refuses to load the R.NET assembly.

The code:

```
import clr  
clr.AddReference("R.NET")
```

Produces:

```
System.IO.IOException: could not add reference to assembly R.NET
```

The assembly is located in a file called `R.NET.dll`, which is stored in the same folder from which I am invoking `ipy.exe`. I have checked that the folder is on `sys.path`. I have tried variations like `clr.AddReference("R.NET.dll")` and `clr.AddReferenceToFile("R.NET.dll")`. None are successful.

Could the problem be that there is a dot (`.`) in the assembly name? How would I work around that?

FWIW I am using Windows 7, [R 2.13.0](http://www.r-project.org), IronPython 2.7, v4.0 of the .NET framework, and R.NET 1.4. I can successfully add a reference to R.NET from the Visual C# Express IDE (under .NET 4.0), and reproduce the [examples from the R.NET homepage.](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath? The . in the name shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath` returns: `System.IO.IOException: file does not exist: C:\Users\wrbrooks\scratch\R.NET.dll`. I assure you that the file does exist. I have tried specifying the path both with single slashes (`\`) and double slashes (`\\`).

Comment: This problem seems to be cropping up elsewhere, too:
[IronPython forum post](http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2010-May/012919.html), and [Another from the IronPython forums](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/26793?ProjectName=ironpython)

Comment: I tried `clr.LoadAssemblyFromFile("R.NET.dll")` and while it did not raise an exception, it also did not load the assembly (it returned a NoneType object, and `import R.NET` failed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you use either Internet Explorer or Chrome, both of which mark downloaded files (with [Zone.Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496697/what-is-zone-identifier)). .NET will refuse to load assemblies that are tainted with said mark.

To remove it, just [unblock the R.NET.dll file](http://blog.jdhardy.ca/2010/09/using-downloaded-ironpython-modules.html). Now you should be good to go. I'll see if I can put in a better error message when trying to load such an assembly.

Comment: Weird. I do use Chrome, but there isn't an "Unblock" button in the R.NET.dll properties. It was downloaded as a .dll file, not in a .zip archive. Would that matter?

Comment: OMG, it worked. For future reference, there was no "Unblock" button in the properties of `R.NET.dll`, as shown in the blog post that @Jeff linked to. I worked around a (broken) link in that post, though, to [this blog post](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2009/09/recursively-unblock-assemblies-with.html) about a Microsoft Sysinternals utility called [`streams`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx). The command `streams -d R.NET.dll` removed the block, and now `clr.AddReference("R.NET.dll"`) works. Huzzah!