filename.Zone.Identifier proplem in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
What is the reason behind automatically creating a file with the name of the files inside any directory but with Zone.Identifier extension? It is bizarre and unexpectable.See the image of some files on my PC
I have tried to delete them but they reappear automatically.

Duplicate of closed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496697/what-are-zone-identifier-files-and-how-do-i-prevent-them-from-being-created
