# NTFS multiple similar attributes

Tags: c++, windows, attributes, ntfs

NTFS files may have multiple file name attributes (corresponding to hard links), that have the same name (are unnamed) and type ($FILE_NAME).

Are there any other cases where attributes of the same type and name appear multiple times in the same file record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like only `$FILE_NAME` attribute can present in a file record multiple times with the same type and name. This is implicitly indicated by looking at `$AttrDef` file content, where only `$FILE_NAME` has bit 2 (Indexed) set. The rest of the attribute types don't have this bit set.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS Files (and directories) can have multiple $DATA attributes. These are called Alternate Data Streams (ADS). See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809725/ntfs-alternate-data-streams). See a good [pdf document](http://www.winitor.com/pdf/NtfsAlternateDataStreams.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, I know it. I mean multiple attributes with same type and name

Comment: You're welcome. In the case of ADS, multiple same $DATA attributes type appear multiple times.

Comment: I meant both type and name to be the same. For ADS only type is the same. Looks like only $FILE_NAME can have this behaviour