# Store metadata information in text file

Tags: file, unix, filesystems, text-files, metadata

I need to store an integer on the filesystem. I have a file (.txt, .log) that represents a simple priority queue. The integer helps with implementing priority the queue. I increment the integer and it needs to be persisted, so that multiple processes can read/write to it.

I could store that integer in a separate file than the file that represents the queue, but I was thinking it would be convenient and maybe slightly more performant to store the integer in the same file as metadata.

Is there a way to store a fairly unbounded (32 bit?) integer as file metadata that would be safe for read/write for a very indefinite amount of time?

Comment: And the reason you can't store it in the file that contains the queue is ... ?

Comment: Because it's possible that this data could accidentally get written to the same portion of the file that represents the queue. I could reserve some bytes in the text file for the integer, but I'd rather just put it somewhere else. Does it not seem any more difficult to put it in the metadata than reserve bytes for the integer in the file itelf? ;) I doubt it.

Comment: You could use [NTFS alternate data streams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105763) on Windows. To my knowledge there's no cross-platform solution. Do note, however, that many tools don't understand them (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809725/ntfs-alternate-data-streams).

Comment: thanks for the info - mostly looking for a unix solution for this, probably won't do cross-platform development in this case

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux is useful to you.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307963/add-a-new-custom-metadata-tag

Comment: Since metadata availability depends on the filesystem type, you'd have to specify the type(s).