# .NET: How to set "extended file attributes" in a cross-platform way?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-5

I need to read and modify [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) in a .NET 5 console application that must work on Windows and Linux (assuming that the files system supports those attributes).

This question has been asked with too(?) specific contexts before:

- [Custom File Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632612/custom-file-properties) (from 2013, no cross-platform)
- [Getting ANY extended file attribute in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308646/getting-any-extended-file-attribute-in-c-sharp) (from 2015, focusing on special cases or platform-specific solutions)
- [Obtaining file extended properties in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872823/obtaining-file-extended-properties-in-net-core) (from 2017, cross-platform, but restricted to some special attributes)

So some years later I want to ask again in a very generic way about those extended file attributes to get a definitive, working, cross-platform answer. About those attributes from the Wikipedia article "[Extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)". I want to add arbitrary ones (not restricted to Title or Author or something). Any key/value pair.

Which .NET APIs should I use?

Comment: You should check if any discussion threads can be found on GitHub, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues or start a new one if needed.

Comment: @LexLi There is indeed a discussion around this here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30321 - but this also ends with a direction I do *not* mean: *I guess meta is directly related to the file type such as an mp3, pdf, or epub.* And this comment about xattr is rather discouraging: *Windows has extended attribute capability but they're almost never used, they may be used more on other platforms but I think it's still quite rare. There would need to be a compelling use case for them to be included in the BCL.* :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API (yet). Here's my proposal to add it: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49604